# Receive data via a rest call using Flask and Dash and update the graphs

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I am implementing a flask application on which I want cytoscape graphs on it. I also want to dynamically update the data by sending a rest API call on the flask application and based on the data the cytoscape graph updates the graphs.

This is the code I have written to do so, but the update process is slow i.e. it receives the data but that data isn't updated on the dash code.

```
import dash  # pip install dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto  # pip install dash-cytoscape==0.2.0 or higher
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from flask import Flask, request   


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

server = Flask(__name__)
app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

@server.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def query_example():
    global data_out
    data =  request.get_data()
    data = (literal_eval(data.decode('utf8')))["data"]
    print("Data Received")
    with open('topology_data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
    return {"Data":True}

with open('topology_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data_out = pickle.load(f)


app1.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        cyto.Cytoscape(
            id='org-chart',
            layout={'name': 'breadthfirst'},
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': '500px'},
            elements=data_out,
            stylesheet=[
                            # Group selectors
                            {
                                'selector': 'node',
                                'style': {
                                    'content': 'data(label)',
                                    'background-color': 'green',
                                    'line-color': 'green'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                'selector': 'edge',
                                'style': {
                                    'background-color': 'green',
                                    'line-color': 'green',
                                    'label': 'data(label)'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                'selector': '[weight = 1]',
                                'style': {
                                    'line-color': 'red'
                                }
                            }
                            ]
        )
    ], className='six columns'),

], className='row')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1.run_server(debug=True)
```

Please tell me a solution to integrate the data receiving process using the REST API and updating the data on the graphs.

Comment: any updates? Please accept the answer if correct, otherwise If it does not answer the question rephrase your problem.  don't leave questions hanging

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. I used the concept of interval instead on n_clicks.

Comment: Are you saying you used Interval to periodically load the data from the pkl file? I've read that using files for such things is dangerous, it would be handy to use the session: is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callbacks to update the data.

```
@app.callback(Output('org-chart', 'elements'),
        [Input("button", "n_clicks")],
    def update_data(nclicks):
        """Retrieves data from api call    
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        nclicks : int | None
            The number of times the button was pressed.
            Used to prevent initial update with empty state.

        """
        if nclicks in [0, None]:
            raise PreventUpdate
        else:
            data = api_call()
            return data
```

You can find a lot more details and an example on https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/callbacks under "Adding and removing elements"

You need to add a button in your app layout of course

```
html.Button('Make api call', id='button', n_clicks=0)
```

Comment: In my use case I don't have any sorts of inputs used that I can use. I want to just update the cyto  graph as soon as an api call is triggered based on the data that we receive in the API call.

Comment: Then you need a button. This button serves as the input to the callback. When pressed the calback is activated. In the callback function you can make the api call and return the data. I updated the code to show how to use a button.