# Is it possible to call dash application with http request and pass there some data?

Tags: python, python-requests, plotly-dash

Is it possible to call the dash application with HTTP requests and pass some data in the requests body?

I have application `app1` under the link:  `http://127.0.0.1:8050/app1`.

I tried to call this `url` with the python requests module like below:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'download': True}


def make_request():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8050/app1"
    r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print(r.request.__dict__)
```

When my server is running and I do `make_request()` then in my response I get all content with HTML that contains my app and in the response of my request I can see that my data is properly sent in requests body:

```
{'_body_position': None,
 '_cookies': <RequestsCookieJar[]>,
 'body': '{"download": true}',
 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.26.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '18'},
 'hooks': {'response': []},
 'method': 'GET',
 'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/app1'}
```

But on the server side, I can't see that the user called the `app1` endpoint with get requests. I tried to print in my app `print(flask.request)` but it doesn't print anything. It seems that nothing happened on server side.

Is it somehow possible to make get requests `from the outside` and get this information inside the server? Because if I just go to a web browser and pass there 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/app1' I see in server flask.request.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but in order to act on outside requests you should setup a server route and define a callback. Check this ticket out: [Receive data via a rest call using Flask and Dash and update the graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315368/receive-data-via-a-rest-call-using-flask-and-dash-and-update-the-graphs)

Calling GET on the URL of your dash application is just returning the html page the same what your browser is doing